# How to import three.module.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking at this [three.js cubemap example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic.html), and it runs fine in my browser when loaded from that page.

After much strain to find and download the files - it does not run?

What am I doing wrong, with this "module" stuff?

I got it to work by changing:

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three.module.js';
...
```

Into:

```html
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script>
...
```

Can anyone explain how to properly import three.module.js? Why is this change necessary when I run the project on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

you should try changing this line:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three.module.js';
```

to this line:

```js
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
```

so the browser understand that it is a **Relative Import** and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ashkan. Although, with latest Chrome (can't turn off updates), that change didn't work. Also Chrome ctrl-s rewrites the save with new subdir - which is why you cannot save the original, nor did it write the three.module.js. Seems user unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks also go to DMGregory for informing map TYPE : equirectangular : could likely learn how now.

Comment: import * as THREE from './three.module.js';  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND -- file placed in same dir and parent dir. parent dir would be ../

Comment: edit the working file this time.. not the saved file -- Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.